# Mongoose find happens after res.render() is called?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

i'm trying to write a "facebook clone" in nodejs with mongoDB. 
The problem I'm having is every time a user goes to a user's profile he needs to get his friends array. the way i'm doing it is like this:

```
router.get("/user/:id/profile", isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
let friends = [];
User.findById(req.params.id, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
        req.flash("error", "There has been an error going to this persons profile.");
        res.redirect("back");
    } else {
        if (user.friends.length > 0) {
            for(var i = 0; i < user.friends.length; i++) {
                User.findById(user.friends[i], (err, friend) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        req.flash("error", "Could not find the friends list")
                        res.redirect("back")
                    } else {
                        friends.unshift({
                            firstName: friend.firstName,
                            lastName: friend.lastName,
                            _id: friend._id
                        })
                        console.log(friends)
                    }
                });
            }
            console.log(friends, "158")
            res.render("user", { userData: user, friends: friends })
        } else {
            // render the page without the friends array.
            res.render("user", { userData: user }); // im calling it userData because i have a local template variable called user and i don't want to over-write it
        }
    }
});
});
```

and what happens is that where i do the console.log(friends) inside the for loop, i get the friends array with everything correct in it, but when i do the console.log(friends) before the res.render("user") the array is empty. any idea why?

Comment: `findById` is async and wont finish unti  `(err, friend) => {...` this callback triggers. Return promises, collect them and wait with `Promise.all(`  or use async/await. What you see in the console is the "live object" not what you have when console.log() is called.

Answer (score 2):

When writing code for node.js you need to get used to async functions as a LOT of addins / classes / code uses this.

Coding is not anymore "linear" but functions are called as soon as previous code is done.

In your case the `findById` starts a process of finding documents in mongoDB and as soon as it found them it will call the (in your case anonymous) callback function with parameters `(err, friend)`.

Your call of `res.render` is outside of that callback and will be immediately called after the `findById` starts. That is to early.
You need to put your `res.render` within the callback to get the data back.

**EDIT: The following code will not run properly because of the for- loop. We need to use promises as shown in Prajvals answer. Please use his second example, as that one works.**

```
User.findById(user.friends[i], (err, friend) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        req.flash("error", "Could not find the friends list")
        res.redirect("back")
    } else {
        friends.unshift({
            firstName: friend.firstName,
            lastName: friend.lastName,
            _id: friend._id
        })
        console.log(friends);
        res.render("user", { userData: user, friends: friends })
    }
});
```

Comment: I think that sums it up nicely. But since this is inside the for-loop, this will send the result on the first completed find, and probably error on the second. (headers has already been sent).

Comment: You are absolutely right... I missed the for- loop. In that case you need to use promises and send the response as soon as alle promises are fullfilled...

Answer (score 1):

It is because of asynchronous nature of node. Using res.render inside your callback function or using promises will sort this out.

<s>Without Promises</s>

```
User.findById(req.params.id, (err, user) => {
if (err) {
    req.flash("error", "There has been an error going to this persons profile.");
    res.redirect("back");
} else {
    if (user.friends.length > 0) {
        for(var i = 0; i < user.friends.length; i++) {
            User.findById(user.friends[i], (err, friend) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    req.flash("error", "Could not find the friends list")
                    res.redirect("back")
                } else {
                    friends.unshift({
                        firstName: friend.firstName,
                        lastName: friend.lastName,
                        _id: friend._id
                    })
                    console.log(friends)
                    res.render("user", { userData: user, friends: friends })
                }
            });
        }
        console.log(friends, "158")

    } else {
        // render the page without the friends array.
        res.render("user", { userData: user }); 
    }
}
});
```

With Promise

```
User.findById(user.friends[i])
.then((friend) => {
     friends.unshift({
        firstName: friend.firstName,
        lastName: friend.lastName,
        _id: friend._id
    })
})
.then(()=>{
    res.render("user", { userData: user, friends: friends })
})
.catch( err=>{
    console.log(err);
    req.flash("error", "Could not find the friends list")
    res.redirect("back")
})
```

----EDIT----

Now async await can also be used. I have not shown it here though.

The one which i have written **without promises will not work**. 
For doing it with / without promise you need to use recursive way for synchronization instead of for loop.

Comment: Your first example will most probaby fail (same as mine) because of the for- loop. Still upvoted for your second example with the promises...

Comment: My bad I had not seen what i was typing. It will not work